# Get cookies for a specific path in JS excluding the root

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I want to get my cookies in JavaScript for a specific path, but I don't want to catch the root cookies.

The **document.cookie** shows both the cookies for my path but also for the root ( **/** ), which I don't want.

I want to show an item once for each of the pages of my website, and I store in a cookie for each page if the user has seen that or not. The problem is that as soon as the user has seen the item in the root page, it doesn't show up anywhere else in the site anymore, because the document.cookie that I do in each page now contains the cookie for the root.

Is there a way that allows me to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to create dynamic cookie key with path included. Like that

```
var cookieName = "shown_at_" + location.pathname.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g,'_');
```

By the way, if you don't need this information (cookies) at server side I suggest to use localStorage instead